# Magneto add to cart not working with loadrunner

Tags: cart, performance, add

I am doing performance testing with loadrunner. The add to cart request is not adding any products to the cart instead it just redirects to another page when i replay with loadrunner. I have correlated the form_key which seems to be the only dynamic value in the request. I cant find anything missing. Does anyone have experience with this?

[image: Request screenshot]

Thanks,
Dave